# Radio buttons for web page with fadeto function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, fade

I have this script using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fotky,.video,.diskusia,.onas,.zbrane,.akcie,.tabroz,.tabburk,.tabhil,.tablest').append('<span class="hover"></span>').each(function () {
        var $span = $('> span.hover', this).css('opacity', 0);
        $(this).hover(function () {
            $span.stop().fadeTo(1000, 1);
        }, function () {
    $span.stop().fadeTo(1000, 0);
        });
    });
});
```

I have this CSS code:

```
.fotky {
clear: both;
position:relative;
display:block;
height: 56px;
width: 126px;
background:url(images/Fotky.png) no-repeat;
background-position: top;
cursor: pointer;
}

.fotky span.hover {
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 56px;
width: 126px;
background: url(images/Fotky.png) no-repeat;
background-position: bottom;
}
```

This is my site [My test site](http://airsoftbanda.tym.sk/css/index.php) How can I make the buttons working as radio buttons so there will be third part of image which will show after click and hide after click on another button. And when clicked part is shown, the hover function should not work on this button. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is my final solution and it works as I need...

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fotky,.video,.diskusia,.onas,.zbrane,.akcie,.tabroz,.tabburk,.tabhil,.tablest').append('<span class="hover"></span>').each(function () {
        var $span = $('> span.hover', this).css('opacity', 0);
        $(this).hover(function () {

            $span.stop().fadeTo(1000, 1);
        }, function () {
    $span.stop().fadeTo(1000, 0);
        });

$(".fotky").mousedown(function(){
$(this).parents('#tlacidlo:first').find(".fotkyk,.videok,.diskusiak,.onask,.zbranek,.akciek").removeClass("fotkyk videok diskusiak onask zbranek akciek");
  $(this).addClass("fotkyk"); 
$span.stop().fadeTo(1000, 0);
end;    
    });

    $(".video").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).parents('#tlacidlo:first').find(".fotkyk,.videok,.diskusiak,.onask,.zbranek,.akciek").removeClass("fotkyk videok diskusiak onask zbranek akciek");
$(this).addClass("videok");
$span.stop().fadeTo(1000, 0);   
    });
```

CSS:

```
#tlacidlo {
height: 400px;
width: 126px;
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.fotky {
clear: both;
position:relative;
display:block;
height: 56px;
width: 126px;
background:url(images/Fotky.png) no-repeat;
background-position: top;
cursor: pointer;
}
.fotky span.hover {
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 56px;
width: 126px;
background: url(images/Fotky.png) no-repeat;
background-position: bottom;
    }
.fotkyk {
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 56px;
width: 126px;
background: url(images/Fotky.png) no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tlacidlo">
<a href="#" class="fotky"></a>
<a href="#" class="video"></a>
<a href="#" class="diskusia"></a>
<a href="#" class="onas"></a>
<a href="#" class="zbrane"></a>
<a href="#" class="akcie"></a>
</div>
```

Of caurse it is only part of code because it is repeating almost same on script and css.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get you correctly but i guess something along this lines should help.

css:

```
.hover{display:none;}
```

script:

```
$('.a, .b, .c').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $span = $('<span class="hover"/>');
    $span.hover(function(){$(this).fadeIn()}, function(){ $(this).fadeOut()});
    $this.filter('a').click(function(e) {
        // do something with the click.
        e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hover = null; // you can save hover function in a var if you want to use it later.
    });
    $this.filter('b').click(function(e) {
        // do something with the click.
        e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hover = null; // you can save hover function in a var if you want to use it later.
    });
    $this.filter('c').click(function(e) {
        // do something with the click.
        e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hover = null; // you can save hover function in a var if you want to use it later.
    });

});
```

Comment: I am still noob in javascript and I can not make it work your way. But let me explain it more clearly. Imagine button.jpg Top of image is showing when default. Bottom when hover. Middle when clicked. Keep the hover function as it is, and add click function which will maybe first change every image to default, and then change clicked image to show middle part and make hover function null. Iam using <a></a> for which is image changed. Also after click I am using .load function so the images are not reloaded. They can stay as I keep them no matter what is loaded on different div.

Comment: Oh I forget, here is the link to "prototype" of my site so you can see how it works. I want to change button image mainly because first time loading whole site images you may see nothing after click on button and you may thing you miss the click. If it changes, you know you have to wait. http://airsoftbanda.tym.sk/css/index.php

Comment: why don't you use pseudo style :hover on css, like a:hover span {background-position:-10px -20px;}

Comment: Because of fade to animation.

Answer (score 0):

So now I have this:

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fg-button")
    .hover(
        function(){ 
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
        },
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover"); 
        }
    )
    .mousedown(function(){
            $(this).parents('.fg-buttonset-single:first').find(".fg-button.ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
            if( $(this).is('.ui-state-active') ){ $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active"); }
            else { $(this).addClass("ui-state-active"); }   
    })
    .mouseup(function(){
        if(! $(this).is('.fg-buttonset-single .fg-button') ){
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.fg-button {height: 56px; width: 126px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; cursor:pointer; position: relative; display:block;}
.ui-state-default { clear: both; background: url(images/Fotky.png) no-repeat; background-position: top;}
.ui-state-hover{background: url(images/Fotky.png) no-repeat; background-position: bottom;}
.ui-state-active {background: url(images/Fotky.png) no-repeat; background-position: center;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fg-buttonset fg-buttonset-single">
<button class="fg-button ui-state-default"></button>
<button class="fg-button ui-state-default"></button>
<button class="fg-button ui-state-default"></button>
<button class="fg-button ui-state-default"></button>
```

This is working as I need but without fadeTo function. How can I implement it there to make it work as on example on top of this page? I made some tryes but no sucess.

Here how the test works http://airsoftbanda.tym.sk/css/test.php

Here how the fadeTo works http://airsoftbanda.tym.sk/css/index.php